# Prevent Jackson from accepting numbers into Date fields in the request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

How can I stop Jackson from accepting numeric values into Date fields in the request body? Jackson seems to be treating them as timestamps and doing the conversion but I would rather have it return a Bad Request response instead.

The field is defined as follows:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
private final Date someDate;
```

Example request:

```
{
    "someDate": 1
}
```

Is deserialized to:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00 CET
```

Comment: It should throw incompatible types error

Comment: @Deadpool it does not. You can try it for yourself.

Comment: Which jackson version you are using?

Comment: okay make sense it is treating that `1` as Date and deserializing to start date of system which is `1970-01-01 01:00:00` @Arqan

Comment: Hmmm why 1 is 01:00:00 not 00:00:01 ??

Comment: AAAAok probably due to CET and pattern is for UTC.

Comment: I am using    jackson-databind:2.9.5 bundled with Spring Boot 2.0.1

Comment: And with LocalDateTime and the module for jakcson? java.util.Date is nealry deprecated by java.tim

Comment: Could you change type to `LocalDateTime`? In that case it will work automatically for it.